# A version of str.isdigit that returns True for decimal fractions?

Tags: python, string, python-2.7

I want to test `raw_input` to make sure that the string contains only numbers and at maximum a single decimal point. `str.isdigit()` looked promising but it will not return True if there is a decimal point in the string.

Ideally, the code would look like this:

```
def enter_number():
    number = raw_input("Enter a number: ")  # I enter 3.5
    if number.SOMETHING:  # SOMETHING is what I am looking for
        float_1 = float(number)
        return float_1
    else
        sys.exit()

half = enter_number() / 2  # = 1.75
double = enter_number() * 2  # = 7
```

Comment: Calling `float(number)` and checking for `ValueError` is the easiest way (this is known as EAFP programming).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suggest the [EAFP](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11360858/2301450) approach.

[`float`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#float) raises the `ValueError` exception if its argument is not a valid float:

```
In [6]: float('bad value')
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-6-dc9476bbdbf8> in <module>()
----> 1 float('bad value')

ValueError: could not convert string to float: 'bad value'
```

You could catch it:

```
number = raw_input("Enter a number: ")
try:
    return float(number)
except ValueError:
    sys.exit()
```

Comment: Thanks! This worked.